# Why do I get the error "OGR error setting feature:5" while changing the attribute of the layer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, error

Getting the error while changing the name of one attribute in the point layer.

> Errors: ERROR: 1 attribute value change(s) not applied.
>
> Provider errors: OGR error setting feature 5: